# React + Jquery plugin that generates dynamic content

Tags: reactjs

I would like to get some help to integrate the Jquery plugin [Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) with My react js component.
I've tried to call the react component directly in the callback : `functionBefore(origin, content)`, the content shows perfectly (list with items) but i receive this error message when an item is clicked.

```
Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot ...
Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``.
```

and here is my component :

```
ListItem = React.createClass({

displayName:
    'ListItem'

getInitialState:->
    {item : ''}

componentWillMount:->
    this.setState({item: this.props.item})

handleClick:(event)->
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log("Clicked")

render:->
    item = this.state.item
    onClick     = this.handleClick.bind(this, item)
    `<li><a className="item" onClick={onClick} href="#">{item.title}</a></li>`

})
```

To render the list view, i loop through an array of objects then i call ListItem foreach.
after that in componentDidMount of my (ListView) i call

```
origin.tooltipster('content', $("#my_selector").html())
content()
```

and here is how i render the all :

```
factory = React.createFactory(ListView)
factory = factory({list : items})
React.render(factory, document.getElementById('my_selector'))
```

origin and content are some Tooltipster variables passed through a the calling method.

__

I think the problem comes from the way tooltipster handles new content, it copy it to his own div and that what makes React reacts to that :D

Any help guys ?

Comment: a note on your React code: rather than `componentWillMount`, do your initial state binding in `getInitialState`, returning an object with `{ item: this.props.item || ... }` with some fallback default in case whoever uses your component forgot to pass in the `item` property

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the trick but that won't solve my problem

Comment: it certainly won't, which is why it's a comment and not an answer. It just stuck out as a thing to fix. As something more related to your problem: can you show the JavaScript that gets generated for your component after running it through the JSX transformer? Because that's where the error will occur (so it's worth looking at that, rather than merely the coffeescript source)

Comment: As the error says, this component is mutating the DOM in a way that is unsupported by React.

Comment: Yes, because i use `$("#my_selector").html()` to get the new content

Comment: Could you please rewrite you code in js. It's pain to read that cofeescript

Comment: Sorry about that, you can use http://js2.coffee/ to convert the code to javascript.